# Choose Specific Radio Button's Value

Tags: php, html

We're trying to create a system where the selected radio(s) current file name will be pushed for future use.. this future use been the replacement of the last lines value.

Our frontend.php file (loops through each file and displays the amount of files worth of radio buttons next to the files data (table))

```html
<?php
foreach($moduleFiles as $moduleFile) {
 $file = file($moduleFile);
 if ($file) {
  echo '<tr>';
  foreach($file as $lines)
  {
   echo  '<td>' . $lines . '</td>';
  }
  echo '<td>
  <form class="form-submit" method="post" action="includes/sendreview.php">
  <div class="form-check">
   <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reviewbutton" value="'.$file.'">
  </div>
  </td>';
 }
 $files++;
}
?> 
</tbody>
</table>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary" >Send for Review</button>
</form>
```

and our backend.php file (line 8 = the last line of the file, in this case the "STATUS" of the module)

```html
<?php 
 $myfile = "../files/modules/" . $_POST['reviewbutton']; 
 $selected = $_POST['reviewbutton']; 
 foreach($selected as $filetoopen)
 {
  foreach($myfile as $lines)
  {
   if ($line = 8)
   {
    fwrite($file, implode('', $lines)); 
    file_put_contents($file, "PROG", FILE_APPEND | LOCK_EX);
    fclose($myfile); 
   }   
  } 
 }  
?>
```

The idea was to get the button's "FILE" value from the "$_POST['reviewbutton']; " however that has the current output of "Array" when we're looking for the output of "filename.txt"

What am i doing wrong? This is my first time using radios with multiple possible selections.

EDIT -

I should have said...

Error on frontend.php =

```
Notice: Array to string conversion in C:\xampp\htdocs\modulemanager.php on line 52
```

line 52 = `<input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="reviewbutton" value="'.$file.'">`

Error on backend.php =

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\sendreview.php on line 5
```

Comment: Are you intending to output a new form for each file? Seems like you'd only want the radio button output in that loop, not a new form each time. Probably won't solve your problem, but a good place to start. Also, close your <tr> tags, even if you don't have to - good practice. Lastly, can you show us the code above your php loops for more complete reference. I'd be happy to dig in more with a better idea. P.S. var_dump() your $_POST variable to see what array you're getting - depending on what actions you take from what you get, post that or update us here with new current progress

Comment: Looks like you need to use $moduleFile instead of $file on line 52, as you create the $file variable as an array of the files lines.

Comment: You're correct - literally just fixed that as you replied here, also managed to remove the clutter from it using "$selected = str_replace('files/modules/', '', $selected);" just trying to fix the error on line 5, now line 6 of backend.php which is foreach($selected as $filetoopen){ error been Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\xampp\htdocs\includes\sendreview.php on line 6 EDIT - I've decided that i've done this bit wrong anyway so might aswell just rewrite the error ed part (thanks for the help anyway :))

Comment: No problem. Good luck from here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the wrong variable. Had to change from $file to $moduleFile in frontend.php

Backend loop was also incorrect, recoded it.